# OS X El Capitan , systemstats:com.apple.telemetry.shutdown

Tags: osx, macintosh

Last night I reinstall OS X El Capitan on may macbook air 11 inch and after I did updates , I shutdown the macbook and went to sleep.İn the morning , I opened it and I saw it was just on sleep. I'm sure I  shut it down last night.Then I check the diagnostic and usage message so that I can see whether someone open it or not and I found this;

[image]

Somehow MBA was opened at 2 a.m.
By the way , MBA has password protection in login window.

Here is my question;
Was someone opened my MBA at 2 a.m or MBA opened by itself .
İf it is opened itself , why?